# How to visualize a distance matrix on a map?

Tags: python, r, data-visualization, geographic-distance

Good morning. I have created a distance matrix in which there are distances between EU regions (NUTS2 level), considering some economic and demographic features. Then I have kept only distances from "Lombardia" (an Italian region) and i have ordered them in ascending order.  I got the following data frame:

```
                                                 distance

Lombardia                                        0.0000000
Emilia-Romagna                                   0.5471997
Veneto                                           0.6692634
País Vasco                                       0.6757556
Piemonte                                         0.7419351
Toscana                                          0.7641841
Niedersachsen                                    0.7910501
Marche                                           0.8066858
Abruzzo                                          0.8587898
Hessen                                           0.8646235
Cataluña                                         0.8855014
```

I would like to get a good graphical visualization of this table, a visualization that explains well the distances between the regions. I thought that I could use geographical data (for example a Spatial Polygon DataFrame), in order to obtain a map of Europe divided into regions: I would color similar regions in the same way.
However, I don't know how to get a chart like this.
How can I visualize my data? 
I usually use R, but I could use also Python.

Comment: I think using a map and showing (dis-)similarity by color of an area is a nice idea (and usually people like this kind of visualisations a lot). Therefore you need to get a shapefile of the desired region that has all the areas you want to show separated. For each of this areas in the shapefile you can add the distanzinformation as a new variable which can be used for colorization. I think this is a nice how to: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/03/choropleth-maps-r.html and this one is great too https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/intro-spatial-rl.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! I read " cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/intro-spatial-rl.pdf " and I managed to get the visualization I wanted!